# How can I detach from Mongo in Spark when using the Mongo Spark Connector?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

Say I run the following code:

```
 var mongoData = MongoSpark.load(sc, contextReadConfig)
 val mongoDF = mongoData.toDF
 //... do some selections, aggregations, etc that all get run on Mongo...
 mongoData.createOrReplaceTempView("myNewView")
```

I do a lot of processing on myNewView, trying different calculations in a loop. When it starts I can see my mongod process spiking on CPU utilization. How can I make it so that when I work with the data it no longer goes all the way back to Mongo? I need to do a lot of calculation on the data and do not want to hammer my Mongo instance.

Edit: This seems to be solvable by calling `.cache()` on the dataframe. Is this guaranteed to disassociate from Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cache()` will store the dataframe into memory, if there are any new dataframes get created then there is a possibility of flushing out the old data from memory.

And when you try to use the first dataframe, it will again query on the database.

Instead of `cache()` you can use `persist()` with the option specifying use both memory and disc so that whenever memory gets overspilled, the data will be written to the disc.

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

mongoDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Comment: Thank you! I plan on doing a lot of computation on AWS spot instances, will storing on disk back everything up to the master node so that even if I lose an instance it won't need to go back to Mongo?